# Oracle Apex Rich Text Editor - Unable to configure Read Only Mode

Tags: oracle-apex

Oracle Apex 22.2.1

Rich Text Editor

initialization code

```
function(options){
    // disable the Autoformat feature
    options.editorOptions.removePlugins.push('Autoformat');
    options.editorOptions.enableReadOnlyMode( 'my-feature-id' ); //Also replaced my_feature_id with true
    // apply a custom toolbar
    options.editorOptions.toolbar = [
        'heading', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'fontSize', 'undo', 'redo'
    ];
    return options;
}
```

I get the following error when the code is run with either an id or the boolean true:

```
   TypeError: options.editorOptions.enableReadOnlyMode is not a function
```

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using the native apex page item read only attribute ?

Comment: When I use the read only attribute it displays the raw html code

Comment: Just tried again. Don't know why, but read only always is working properly. It didn't before. There might have been some other changes I didn't track. I will continue to test.  Thanks

Comment: tested good I will close this question

Answer (score 0):

Koen Lostrie gave me the correct answer of using the native apex page item read only attribute. Do not use the rich text editor method to set it to read only.